# how to yarn link a package in lerna?

Tags: frontend, lerna

I'm working on a project which relies on local lerna packages(project folder is not in lerna folder, they are independent), I want to run `yarn link` in a lerna package, in order to use `yarn link xx` in my project to symlink the single lerna package. But I keeps get error `Unknown Syntax Error: Not enough positional arguments.`
[image]

yarn version: 3.6.4

Any solutions are appreciated